# How can I get access to a hard drive's contents on a dead laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, toshiba-laptop

Is there any way possible to get data off my laptop HDD without removing it from the laptop? It has problems possibly with the CPU or RAM and can't load the OS but it does turn on.

I don't want to take it apart as I can still get warranty, but there's a lot of data I'd like to retrieve.

The laptop model is a Toshiba Satellite L50-A.

Comment: As has been noted by others, if the RAM or CPU is bad, booting from CD or USB will be of little use. You will need to remove the HDD, this will most likely NOT void the warranty if done carefully.

Answer (score 6):

Simply removing the HDD to remove the data shouldn't void the warranty. Get a HDD to USB adaptor, they're worth their weight in gold.

Comment: This is the right answer, IMO. After you copy everything, use it to wipe the drive before you put it back in the machine.

Answer (score 2):

On another machine, make a bootable CD/DVD or a bootable USB drive and boot with it.

Try these guides:

- [Knoppix](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html)
- [Ubuntu USB Stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Comment: This is not likely to help if the problem is a bad CPU or memory (or any other problem that isn't the HDD)...

Answer (score 1):

Most laptop hard drives are easily accessible. Just a few screws and pop the panel off the back. Try the hard drive in another computer or a cradle if you have one. If you insist on not removing the HDD you can try booting from a live disk with persistent memory to transfer your data, but if you suspect the CPU or RAM is at fault it won't matter the boot device. It won't boot.

Also, as MDT Guy said, removing the hdd won’t void any warranty